# Issues creating a model instance - TypeMismatch error in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting an error and I don't understand why.  I have a form that passes to the control input to create a model instance with.

Here is the form:

```
=form_for :message, :url => {:action => 'create', :controller => 'messages'} do |f|
    =f.text_area :body, :placeholder => 'Enter your message.', :size => '40x5'
    =f.hidden_field :subject, value: "RE:#{@message.subject}"
    =f.hidden_field :parent, value: @message.id
    =f.hidden_field :receiver, value: @message.sender
    =f.submit 'Reply'
```

Here is the controller:

```
def create
    user = User.find_by_username(params[:message][:receiver])#remove receiver and give it a varibale -rg 4/29
    if user ||= User.find_by_id(params[:message][:receiver]).username#valid entry -rg 4/29
        params[:message].delete('receiver')
        params[:message][:status] = 'unread'#set status -rg 4/29
        params[:message][:sender] = @current_user#set sender -rg 4/29
        # raise params.inspect
13 =>   @message = Message.create!(params[:message])#create message! -rg 4/29
        if parent = params[:message][:parent]#checks if this is a reply to another message -rg 4/29
            Message.find_by_id(parent).update_attributes(:child => @message)#updates parent message to have this message as child -rg 4/29
        end
        @message.received<<user#adds receiver to database
        flash[:notice] = "Message was successfully sent."
        redirect_to messages_path
    else
        flash[:warning] = "There is no user with that username."
        redirect_to messages_path
    end
end
```

And my Message Model:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :body, :subject, :status, :sender, :receiver,:parent, :child
   belongs_to :sent, :class_name => 'User'
   has_and_belongs_to_many :received, :class_name => 'User'
   belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Message'
   has_one :child, :class_name => 'Message'
end
```

The error I am getting, including trace:

```
 ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in MessagesController#create

 Message(#41016000) expected, got String(#17696120)

 Rails.root: /home/renee/classes/SE/Brainstormy
 Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

 app/controllers/messages_controller.rb:13:in `create'
```

Here are the params being passed:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"yLYTXNTjluDk15dm554vpjom7hlQCC2d+hGmkuLJcEE=",
 "message"=>{"body"=>"j",
 "subject"=>"RE:j",
 "parent"=>"1",
 "status"=>"unread",
 "sender"=>2},
 "commit"=>"Reply"}
```

It's interesting because I have a second form that uses the same controller that works perfectly.  It seems that the extra field I have, `:parent` is the culprit.  But I want don't want to pass it a message.  What I want is to pas it an integer that is the id.  But it's getting passed as a string.  Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: show us the params on that request, especially params[:message]

Comment: why not just params[:message][:parent] = params[:message][:parent].to_i before creating your object?

Comment: I thought about that.  But that doesn't work becuase for some reason is expecting an object, not a string or an int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because you are passing in a string (`f.hidden_field :parent, value: @message.id`) into the parent association method which requires a Message object. What you want to do is set the foreign_key field for the parent association to the message id.

If the foreign_key is parent_id, then the hidden field should be this:

```
f.hidden_field :parent_id, value: @message.id
```

You'll have to check if making `:parent` accessible is the same as making `:parent_id` accessible otherwise it won't get set.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Alain!  I did as you suggested and I still get that error.

Comment: try setting it manually in your controller action and see if it still errors:
    
    # MessagesController#create
    @message.parent = Message.find_by_id(params[:parent_id])